# Viewing all iptables rules

Tags: iptables

Is there a way to view `iptables` rules in a bit more detail?

I recently added masquerade to a range of IPs:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
service iptables save
service iptables restart
```

Which has done what I want it to, but when I use:

```
iptables -L
```

I get the same output as I normally get:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target    prot opt source        destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target    prot opt source        destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target    prot opt source        destination
```

How can I see the rules including the ones I add? (system is CentOS 6)

Answer (score 158, accepted):

When using the `-L`, `--list` option to list the current firewall rules, you also need to specify the appropriate Netfilter table (one of `filter`, `nat`, `mangle`, `raw` or `security`). So, if you’ve added a rule for the `nat` table, you should explicitly specify this table using the `-t`, `--table` option:

```
iptables --table nat --list
```

Or using the options short form:

```
iptables -t nat -L
```

If you don’t specify a specific table, the `filter` table is used as the default.

---

For faster results, it can be useful to also include the `-n`, `--numeric` option to print numeric IP addresses instead of hostnames, thus avoiding the need to wait for reverse DNS lookups.

You can get even more information by including the `-v`, `--verbose` option.

Answer (score 142):

`iptables` controls five different tables: `filter`, `nat`, `mangle`, `raw` and `security`. On a given call, `iptables` only displays or modifies one of these tables, specified by the argument to the option `-t` (defaulting to `filter`). To see the complete state of the firewall, you need to call `iptables` on each of the tables successively.

Additionally, to get an accurate representation of the rules, you need to pass the option `-v`. Otherwise some important criteria are omitted in the output, such as the interface in filter rules (e.g. a rule that says “accept everything” and a rule that says “accept everything on the loopback interface” can only be distinguished with `-v`).

Thus, to get a complete presentation of the netfilter rules, you need

```
iptables -vL -t filter
iptables -vL -t nat
iptables -vL -t mangle
iptables -vL -t raw
iptables -vL -t security
```

Alternatively, you can call the `iptables-save` program, which displays all the rules in all tables in a format that can be parsed by `iptables-restore`. This format is also reasonably readable by humans (it's pretty much like a series of calls to the `iptables` command to build the table).

Comment: `filter`, `nat`, `mangle`, `raw`, `security`... and `mark` looks like another one. Having a hard time finding a way to list all the **tables**, especially if some are system dependent.  Someone asked the same thing a while ago with no real answer: https://comp.os.linux.networking.narkive.com/fDfacHDC/iptables-how-to-list-tables

Answer (score 65):

`iptables -S` does the trick for me. It seems to list all the active rules, even when the service is off.

From the man page:

> -S, --list-rules [chain]
>   Print all rules in the selected chain. If no chain is selected, all chains are printed like iptables-save. Like every other iptables command, it applies to the specified table (filter is the default).

Comment: This is a really kwl answer, I've also noticed that /sbin/service iptables status gives a similar output

Comment: +1. No 'seems' about it- from the man page: "-S, Print  all  rules  in the selected chain.  If no chain is selected, all chains are printed like iptables-save". This is the one I usually need.

Comment: i did not find this to be the case. `iptables -S` does not show all my nat rules, which i can see when i run `iptables -L -t nat`

Comment: @MikeS From the man page, BOTH commands operate only on the specified table, filter by default. "Like every other iptables command, it applies to the specified table (filter is the default)." The wording in the documentation is copied almost identically for -S and -L, they only differ in formatting of the output, not the rules printed. This is true at least on Ubuntu 16.04 which on my system is iptables v1.6.0.

Comment: Agree with @mulllhausen here.  I needed "sudo iptables --table nat --list" to show my nat table rules.  the "-S" flag by itself did not show them.

Answer (score 24):

What I do is to execute `iptables-save > iptables_bckp`, this would backup all the layers, then edit the file and restore the iptables `iptables-restore < iptables_bckp`

```
# iptables-save > iptables_bckp
# vim iptables_bckp
# iptables-restore < iptables_bckp
```

You can make a double backup so you modify one of them without losing your past iptables.

This is a personal practice, I'm not saying this is the best way but for me works great.

Give a try

Comment: This is the only realistic answer I have found so far that actually dumps all of the tables too.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
# lsmod | grep ip_tables
ip_tables              13193  4 iptable_raw,iptable_mangle,iptable_nat,iptable_filter
```

To find all tables and show specific rule in table.

Comment: A better way to find the table names is `cat /proc/net/ip_tables_names` and `cat /proc/net/ip6_tables_names`

Answer (score 4):

The `iptables` command also requires you to specify the table otherwise it defaults to filter table. So try:

```
iptables -t nat -L
```

Answer (score 2):

If it will really help you could write a bash script and put it in a folder that is reference by your path or reference it via an alias in the ~/.bashrc file.

AllRules.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

 echo "Filter table:"
 iptables -t filter -vL

 echo "Nat table:"
 iptables -t nat -vL

 echo "Mangle table:"
 iptables -t mangle -vL

 echo "Raw table:"
 iptables -t raw -vL

 echo "Security table:"
 iptables -t security -vL

 echo 
 echo "All rules in all tables printed"
```

Remember to give your new bash script execute permissions with `chmod`

If permission is an issue you may have to add sudo in front of all the `iptables` commands.

Answer (score 2):

```
iptables -vnxL
iptables -vnxL -tnat
```

possibly additionally, though these are very very rarely used:

```
iptables -vnxL -traw
iptables -vnxL -tmangle
iptables -vnxL -tsecuriy
```