# How to get a deterministic complete dump of all iptables rules?

Tags: shell-script, iptables

How to get a deterministic complete dump of all iptables rules?

By complete, I mean all tables of iptables.

By deterministic, I mean when the command is run multiple times without modifying any iptables, it should always output the same.

Use case: Refactoring a firewall script. Using for example a for loop rather than writing similar command multiple times and stuff like that. Running the iptables-dump command before and after to check the refactoring has not changed any actual iptables rules.

As per [Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206057/49297) by [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206057/49297), to get a complete output, `-v` should to be used.

> `iptables` controls five different tables: `filter`, `nat`, `mangle`, `raw` and `security`. On a given call, `iptables` only displays or modifies one of these tables, specified by the argument to the option `-t` (defaulting to `filter`). To see the complete state of the firewall, you need to call `iptables` on each of the tables successively.
>
> Additionally, to get an accurate representation of the rules, you need to pass the option `-v`. Otherwise some important criteria are omitted in the output, such as the interface in filter rules (e.g. a rule that says “accept everything” and a rule that says “accept everything on the loopback interface” can only be distinguished with `-v`).
>
> Thus, to get a complete presentation of the netfilter rules, you need
>
> ```
> iptables -vL -t filter
> iptables -vL -t nat
> iptables -vL -t mangle
> iptables -vL -t raw
> iptables -vL -t security
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you can call the `iptables-save` program, which displays all the rules in all tables in a format that can be parsed by `iptables-restore`. This format is also reasonably readable by humans (it's pretty much like a series of calls to the `iptables` command to build the table).

But when using `-v`, the packages and bytes counter will be added. Thereby making the output non-deterministic.

How to get best of both worlds? How to get a deterministic complete dump of all iptables rules?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `iptables-save` command has a very straightforward output. The varying parts are in square brackets after a rule, or in comments:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sun Jan 10 16:02:30 2016
: INPUT ACCEPT [38:2132]
```

It then becomes an exercise to nullify or even remove such entities, resulting in a completely deterministic output that can still be re-read with `iptables-restore`:

```
iptables-save | sed -e 's/\[[0-9:]*\]/[0,0]/' -e '/^#/d'
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0,0]
....
```